# How to enable "When Run" column in SSRS report manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to populate When Run field in ssrs report manager?

When you click show Details in Report Manager the last field is not populating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to find out when a report was last run, you will get a lot more information going into the `ReportServer` database directly.

This will get you what you want:

```
select C.[Name]
      ,C.ExecutionTime
      ,max(EL.TimeStart) as LastRunTime
from dbo.ExecutionLog as EL
    inner join dbo.[Catalog] as C
        on EL.ReportID = C.ItemID
where c.[Name] = 'Your Report Name'
group by C.[Name]
        ,C.ExecutionTime;
```

Though I would recommend having a look around `Catalog` and `Execution Log` to see if there is anything else that you may find useful, like the report parameters that were used, how long the report took to run and who ran it etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am looking to see in report manager directly without running any report. I found out that it has been fixed for release 2014. I will give this a try. Thanks again :)